# slow INSERT/UPDATE on Remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert, remote-server

There are 2 SQL Servers let's call them `Master` and `Slave`. There is a stored procedure on `Master` that basically does:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Slave.Table1

SELECT all FROM Master.Table1 WHERE Id > maxIdFromSlave

INSERT results INTO Slave.Table1
```

The execution of this stored procedure on `Master` server is about 10-15x slower than execution of alternative stored procedure on `Slave` server.

Using stored procedure does not give any difference here, I have also tried it with simple query.

I suppose there might be something like Distributed Transactions in the server core, but I do not use any transactions.

I wonder how the SQL Server works depending on whether insert/update/delete is on remote server

Maybe when insert/update is on remote server(Slave), the calling server(Master) is waiting for an answer?

Comment: Run the Stored Procedure in SQL Management Studio and have a look at the actual execution plan. Are there any obvious delays in it? If not, possibly a networking \server configuration issue?

Comment: Is the hardware of the 2 servers identical?

Comment: Hello. Why not create a simple app (vb or C#) ?

Comment: @Slim the Master server is more powerful.

Comment: @OrlandoHerrera actually there is a windows service that is responsible for the synchronization from Master server to Slave server that calls stored procedures.